# Swift: Map returns 4 values as the distance between 2 points, why?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3

I am calculatig the distance between 2 points. For the first point, I am assigning the latitude and the longtiude. The second point coordinates wherever the user clicks on the map. Every thing works perfectly, except the answer being printed 4 times.

- I tried to return the first index(it turned out the first index is 4 
  values).
- I tried to add these values to a set to delete the repeated ones (it did not work).
- I tried to make a loop, and break after the first time (Still return 4 values).
  Here where I am creating the annotation for the user click (inside viewdidAppear):

,

```
let uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MapViewController.longpress(gestureRecognizer:)))
        uilpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2
        map.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgr)
```

And this is the function that calculates the distance (After the function viewdidAppear):

```
 @objc func longpress(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer){
    let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.map)
    let coordinates = map.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: self.map)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = coordinates
    annotation.title = "Destination"
    map.addAnnotation(annotation)

    let source = CLLocation(latitude: 5, longitude: 5)

    let distination = CLLocation(latitude: coordinates.latitude, longitude: coordinates.longitude)

    let distanceInMeters = source.distance(from: distination)
    let distanceInMiles = String(Int(distanceInMeters/1.6))

    myArrayDataStructure.myArray.append(distanceInMiles)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(myArrayDataStructure.myArray, forKey: "items")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is how you handle the gesture. A "long press" gesture (like others) has several states. A gesture action is called when the gesture begins, when it ends, when it is cancelled, and in the case of a "long press", as the gesture is updated.

You want to perform your distance calculations only when the gesture's state is "ended".

```
@objc func longpress(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer){
    if gestureRecognizer.state = .ended {
        // your code here
    }
}
```